# confusions on xinput query-state outputs

Tags: linux, x11, hardware, acpi, xinput

When I run xinput query-state on something such as a power button, it returns 247 keys. Shouldn't it just be a single button? I read something online about acpi that explains this, but I am not sure I understood it.